# Custom URL Attribute Magento

Tags: magento

So I've setup a Group Product that pulls in Simple products (see here: http://174.121.8.194/~mascoins/spectrumstandards/index.php/test/low-level-oxygenates-3.html). What my client is wanting is to pull in a particular simple product, that when you click on it, it goes to that particular product page. So for example, if they clicked on 10 PPM WT. LOW-OX [10 x 2 ML AMPOULES], and just 10 PPM WT. LOW-OX [10 x 2 ML AMPOULES], it would go that product page.

The reason why is my client is wanting to present different products within a Group, and then if they want the custom product, they would click on the custom product within that group to go configure that custom product. Does this make sense? Is this possible?

Thanks

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, first thing you need to do is rewrite the product view phtml file or edit product view phtml in your custom theme

The following snippet will get you items of grouped product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){
    $groupdProducts =  $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
}

// The get the product urls 

foreach ($groupdProducts as $_product):

    $_product_url = $_product->getProductUrl();
    echo '<a href='.$_product_url/>'.$_product->getName().'</a>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Hmm, cool. That looks like it would apply for every associated product though...is there a way to make it for a specific product, perhaps through an attribute?